# Field Creation in Email Pagelayout

Tags: apex, administration, user-admin

I want to create a PickList Field in below screen is it possible,[image: How to add custom field]

Comment: you want to list all the available objects in your organisation as picklist values

Comment: @Sravan No, Just i need to create a picklist field in that i have to mention name Email, why because i am tracking number of emails in reports to populate the picklistfield in reports so i want to create a picklist in above page is it possible..??

Answer (score 1):

You might have to overload the same page(with VF Page).

Or, Use a homePage component(with jQuery to append a new DOM element). Then you can assign the field with an field ID(lkID).

The question here can be, which field are you trying to map to the picklist?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add anything to this page and it might be impractical to recreate it completely as VF + replace all the places from which you end up on emailAuthor.jsp (add custom button on activities rel list, hijack when someone clicks "Reply" on a Case email message...).

Try prompting your users to select the picklist value after the email was sent (it'll be recorded as a Task with status = Completed). Or if you can somehow determine the value you need from the email's subject/body - try a `before insert` trigger on Tasks where subject starts with "Email:" :/